# Show "still loading" in django

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, django-templates

I have two things I want to address, and I'm new to `django` and styling: First, I have this algorithm I'm running on the upload file and it takes time to load, so I want to show loading message or so until the `output.csv` is generated and ready to download (after home function is executed). I'm very new to styling and templating, can anyone help me on how to do that?

My files are like this:

```
view.py:

from __future__ import division
from django.shortcuts import render
from uploader.models import UploadForm,Upload
from uploader.models import Book
import io
from io import TextIOWrapper
import csv
from csv import DictReader
from io import StringIO
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
import csv
import logging
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.cluster import AgglomerativeClustering
import csv
from csv import DictReader
import numpy
from numpy.random import *
import numpy as np
import random
from functools import partial
from sklearn.metrics import pairwise_distances_argmin_min
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform
import pandas as pd
import functools
from scipy import spatial
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
from math import pi, acos
from sklearn.metrics.cluster import adjusted_rand_score
from sklearn.metrics import jaccard_similarity_score
import pprint
from sklearn.decomposition import TruncatedSVD
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.preprocessing import Normalizer
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans, MiniBatchKMeans
from sklearn.cluster import MeanShift, estimate_bandwidth
from sklearn.datasets.samples_generator import make_blobs
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage
import codecs
from django.utils.encoding import smart_text
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.conf import settings #or from my_project import settings
from django.http import StreamingHttpResponse
from wsgiref.util import FileWrapper
from django.utils.encoding import smart_str

def send_file(request):

  filename = settings.MEDIA_ROOT +'/'+ 'output1.csv'
  #filename= r"C:\Users\A6B0SZZ\PycharmProjects\sample\media\output1.csv"
  download_name ="output1.csv"
  wrapper      = FileWrapper(open(filename))
  response     = HttpResponse(wrapper,content_type='text/csv')
  response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=%s"%download_name
  return response



def home(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        img = UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if img.is_valid():

           # paramFile = request.FILES['pic']
            paramFile =io.TextIOWrapper(request.FILES['pic'].file)
            portfolio1 = csv.DictReader(paramFile)
            print(type(paramFile))

            users = [row["BASE_NAME"] for row in portfolio1]
            print(len(users))

            my_list = users
            vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
            dtm = vectorizer.fit_transform(my_list)

            lsa = TruncatedSVD(n_components=100)
            dtm_lsa = lsa.fit_transform(dtm)
            dtm_lsa = Normalizer(copy=False).fit_transform(dtm_lsa)
            similarity = np.asarray(numpy.asmatrix(dtm_lsa) * numpy.asmatrix(dtm_lsa).T)
            k = len(my_list)
            dist1 = (1- similarity)
            # dist1=similarity
            # dist1.astype(float)
            #print(dist1)
            # print(cosine_similarity(tfidf_matrix[3:4], tfidf_matrix))
            # float dist = 1 - similarity;
            data2 = np.asarray(dist1)
            arr_3d = data2.reshape((1, k, k))
            # arr_3d= 1- arr_3d
            #print(arr_3d)

            no_clus = 40
            for i in range(len(arr_3d)):
                # print (i+1910)
                # km = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=no_clus, linkage='ward').fit(arr_3d[i])
                km = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=no_clus, linkage='average').fit(arr_3d[i])
                # km = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=no_clus, linkage='complete').fit(arr_3d[i])
                # km = MeanShift()
                # km = KMeans(n_clusters=no_clus, init='k-means++')
                # km = MeanShift()
                #  km = km.fit(arr_3d[i])
                # print km
                labels = km.labels_

            csvfile = settings.MEDIA_ROOT +'\\'+ 'images\\export.csv'

            csv_input = pd.read_csv(csvfile, encoding='latin-1')
            csv_input['cluster_ID'] = labels
            csv_input['BASE_NAME'] = my_list
            csv_input.to_csv(settings.MEDIA_ROOT +'/'+ 'output.csv', index=False)
            clus_groups = list()
            for j in range(no_clus):
                # print(" cluster no %i:%s" % (j, [my_list[i] for i, x in enumerate(labels) if x == j]))
                list_of_ints = ([my_list[i] for i, x in enumerate(labels) if x == j])
                clus_groups.append('  '.join(list_of_ints))
            vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
            dtm = vectorizer.fit_transform(my_list)

            lsa = TruncatedSVD(n_components=100)
            dtm_lsa = lsa.fit_transform(dtm)
            dtm_lsa = Normalizer(copy=False).fit_transform(dtm_lsa)
            similarity = np.asarray(numpy.asmatrix(dtm_lsa) * numpy.asmatrix(dtm_lsa).T)
            k = len(my_list)
            dist1 = 1 - similarity

            data2 = np.asarray(dist1)
            arr_3d = data2.reshape((1, k, k))
            # arr_3d= 1- arr_3d


###########################################here#######################
            no_clus = 5
            for i in range(len(arr_3d)):

                km = KMeans(n_clusters=no_clus, init='k-means++')
                km = km.fit(arr_3d[i])

                labels2 = km.labels_

                print(labels2)

            labels = labels.tolist()
            labels2 = labels2.tolist()
            # new=list()


            csv_input = pd.read_csv(settings.MEDIA_ROOT +'/'+ 'output.csv',encoding='latin-1')
            labels1 = csv_input['cluster_ID']
            new_list = []
            for k in labels1:
                new_list.append(labels2[k])  # lookup the value in list2 at the index given by list1

            print(new_list)
            print(len(new_list))
            csv_input = pd.read_csv(settings.MEDIA_ROOT +'/'+ 'output.csv',encoding='latin-1')
            csv_input['cluster_ID'] = labels
            csv_input['BASE_NAME'] = my_list
            csv_input['User_Map'] = new_list
            csv_input.to_csv(settings.MEDIA_ROOT + '/' + 'output1.csv', index=False)
            filename= settings.MEDIA_ROOT +'/'+ 'output.csv'
            send_file(request)
           # my_list = portfolio
            #save_file('output1.csv')
          #  csv(request)
          #  return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('labels'))
            return render(request, 'home.html', {'labels': labels})
    else:
        img=UploadForm()
    images=Upload.objects.all()
    return render(request,'home.html',{'form':img,'images':images})
```

My `home.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="padding:40px;margin:40px;border:1px solid #ccc">
    <h1>Upload the CSV File to Run the Algorithm on:</h1>
    <form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %} {{form}}
         <input type="submit" value="Upload" />

    </form>

<a href="/media/output1.csv">Download CSV File</a>

</div>
</body>
</html>




url.py:

from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from uploader import views


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^upload/$', 'uploader.views.home', name='labels'),
    url(r'^media/output1.csv', 'uploader.views.send_file'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I'm assuming I need to add staff to my html file, or to the template dir in general. I appreciate the help.
The second thing is that I need a box so that the user will determine how many clusters for the input, right now I defined it as 5, right before when I mentioned "#####here#####".. How can I do that? I appreciate the help with the code.

`One more` thing,how I can make the link of `download csv file` show up only when the `home` function is executed?

**Edit:**
I tried to develop the number input box, which it should be as `get.request` I think:

My form.py

```
from django import forms

class NameForm(forms.Form):
    your_name = forms.CharField(label='Your name', max_length=100)
```

View.py

```
from .forms import NameForm


def get_name(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'GET':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = NameForm(request.GET)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            # ...
            # redirect to a new URL:
            return render_to_response('new.html')

    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        form = NameForm()

    return render(request, 'new.html', {'form': form})
```

Later in `view.py`, inside `home function`:

```
no_clus=get_name(request)
            for i in range(len(arr_3d)):

                km = KMeans(n_clusters=no_clus, init='k-means++')
                km = km.fit(arr_3d[i])

                labels2 = km.labels_
                # error = km.inertia_
                print(labels2)



new.html

   <form  method="get">
    <label for="your_name">Number of Users: </label>
    <input id="your_name" type="text" name="your_name" value="{{ current_name }}">
    <input type="submit" style="display:none;">
</form>


Error:
unorderable types: int() < HttpResponse()

Edit:
```

Want optional input box, if user won't input anything, the default function after the else should execute, I tried the following but didn't work:

view.py:

```
def number_cluster(request, data_size):
    if request.method == 'GET':
       img1 = Book(request.GET)
        if img1.is_valid():
            no_cluster = int(request.POST.get('num_clusters1'))
            return render(int(no_cluster), {'form': img1})
        else:
            no_cluster = data_size / 2.34
            return (int(no_cluster))
```

**Models:**

```
class Book(models.Model):
      description = models.TextField(blank=True)


**`New.html`**
```

Optional : Please insert Number of Clusters

Comment: The "still loading" interaction that you are looking at is client side. Assuming that you use javascript to submit that form, what you can probably do is just before submitting the form you can show an overlay covering entire screen and wait for the response to come from your backend. Once you have the response you can hide that overlay.

Comment: can you show me with example of code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not the final solution - but to give an idea:
As Rajesh did mention in the comment this can be addressed client side (with JavaScript/jQuery). So you could add the desired message when submitting the form.

#### Question 1

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        #loading {
            background: red;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div style="padding:40px;margin:40px;border:1px solid #ccc">
    <h1>Upload the CSV File to Run the Algorithm on:</h1>
    <form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %} {{form}}
         <input type="submit" value="Upload" />

    </form>

<a href="/media/output1.csv">Download CSV File</a>

</div>

<script>
    $(function(){
        $('form').on('submit', function(e){
            $('body').append('<div id="loading">Loading...</div>')
        });
    })
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

#### Question 2

In your template:

```
<!-- template.html -->
<form ...>
    ...
    <input type="number" name="num_clusters" min="1" max="500">
    ...
```

In your view:

```
# view.py
def home(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        num_clusters = request.POST.get('num_clusters', 10) # 10 as default
```

Comment: what to pass instead of function()?

Comment: What do you mean? This is just a shorthand for jQuery's [$( document ).ready()](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Comment: Using your solution, not sure how to connect the script code with my function of home, parameter (e) is not defined

Comment: In `$('form').on('submit', function(e)...` the `e` references to the invoking DOM event. In the case described it's not relevant. Just there for reference because you eventually would want do do some processing/validation prior to submitting the form.

Comment: The  `$('form').on('submit', ...` part adds an event-listener to your form 'submit' action. So the callback function is called when such an event is triggered.

Comment: so I'm very new to this, so we added here an event-listener,  but how to call this event, not sure what to do next

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114764/discussion-between-ohrstrom-and-lelo).

Comment: @ohrstorm, can you help with optional input box? I edited the question what what I tried

Comment: @Lelo I would recommend to split this out into a separate question with the exact problem and relevant code bits extracted. This question here is already much to broad... Questions and answers on SO should be about a more or less specific topic - so that they are of help for other people as well.

Comment: I posted it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37887231/optional-input-box-in-django

Comment: can you take a look at it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37887231/optional-input-box-in-django